# php I'm having trouble with the update on my CRUD

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, wamp

I tried disabling strict mode, changing precio to int, tried to convert it to double but so far nothing works. Can anyone recommend me a good book or a good youtube channel on web development?. The CRUD works so far as insert and deleting goes. But update doesn't work. When I disabled strict mode I stopped getting the warning #1265 but it didn't update anything. I'm using WAMP, phpmyadmin and Notepad++. I've also changed the $_GET to POST on my update an it didnt work

```
<?php
   include("conexion.php");
   $registros=$base->query("select * from articulo")- 
   >fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if(isset($_POST['cr']))
{
    $nombre=$_POST["Nom"];
    $cantidad=$_POST["Can"];
    $precio=$_POST["Pre"];
    $costo=$_POST["Cos"];
    $sql="INSERT INTO articulo (nombre,cantidad,precio,costo) VALUES(:nom, :can, :pre, :cos)";
    $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);
    $resultado->execute(array(":nom"=>$nombre,":can"=>$cantidad,":pre"=>$precio,":cos"=>$costo ));
    header("Location:index.php");
}
?>

<h1>CRUD<span class="subtitulo">Create Read Update Delete</span></h1>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post"> 
<table width="50%" border="0" align="center">
<tr >
  <td class="primera_fila">Id</td>
  <td class="primera_fila">Nombre</td>
  <td class="primera_fila">Cantidad</td>
  <td class="primera_fila">Precio</td>
  <td class="primera_fila">Costo</td>
  <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
  <td class="sin">&nbsp;</td>
</tr> 

<?php
    foreach($registros as $articulo):?> 
<tr>
  <td> <?php echo $articulo->Id_campo?> </td>
  <td> <?php echo $articulo->nombre?> </td>
  <td> <?php echo $articulo->cantidad?></td>
  <td> <?php echo $articulo->precio?> </td> 
  <td> <?php echo $articulo->costo?> </td> 
  <td class="bot"><a href="borrar.php?Id=<?php echo $articulo->Id_campo?>"><input type='button' name='del' id='del' value='Borrar'></a></td>      
  <td class='bot'><a href="editar.php?Id=<?php echo $articulo->Id_campo?> & nom=<?php echo $articulo->nombre?> & can=<?php echo $articulo->cantidad?> & pre=<?php echo $articulo->precio?> & cos=<?php echo $articulo->costo?>"><input type='button' name='up' id='up' value='Actualizar'></a></td>

</tr>       
<?php
    endforeach;
?>
```

And this is the code for the update php

```
  <h1>ACTUALIZAR</h1>
<?php

include("conexion.php");
if (!isset($_POST["bot_actualizar"]))
{
    $Id=$_GET["Id"];
    $nom=$_GET["nom"];
    $can=$_GET["can"];
    $pre=$_GET["pre"];
    $cos=$_GET["cos"];  
}
else
{
    $Id=$_GET["Id"];
    $nom=$_GET["nom"];
    $can=$_GET["can"];
    $pre=$_GET["pre"];
    $cos=$_GET["cos"];
    $sql="UPDATE articulo SET nombre=:miNom, cantidad=:miCan, precio=:miPre, 
    costo=:miCos WHERE Id_campo=:miId";
    $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);
    $resultado->execute(array(":miId"=>$Id, ":miNom"=>$nom, ":miCan"=>$can, 
    ":miPre"=>$pre, ":miCos"=>$cos));
    header("Location:index.php");
}
?>

<p>

</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
 <table width="25%" border="0" align="center">
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><label for="id"></label>
  <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $Id?>"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Nombre</td>
  <td><label for="nom"></label>
  <input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" value="<?php echo $nom?>"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Cantidad</td>
  <td><label for="can"></label>
  <input type="text" name="can" id="can" value="<?php echo $can?>"></td> 
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Precio</td>
  <td><label for="pre"></label>
  <input type="text" name="pre" id="pre" value="<?php echo $pre?>"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Costo</td>
  <td><label for="cos"></label>
  <input type="text" name="cos" id="cos" value="<?php echo $cos?>"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="bot_actualizar" 
   id="bot_actualizar" value="Actualizar"></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </form>
 <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Comment: This attribute is kind of redundant, don't you think? `action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>"`

Comment: `header("Location:index.php");` will not work, because you have already started outputting HTML.

Comment: Start using a real IDE, for example VS Code. You can then install linters, intelephense, code formatters and other extensions, which will improve your coding skills. As for other recommendations we can't do that here on StackOverflow. The topic is too broad.

Comment: It doesn't update because your using $_GET vars, when they should be $_POST..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things.

1. Your form is using `POST` method and for your update you are looking for `GET` request.
2. The header sent at the end of the update is useless as you already start diplaying the page with the `H1...`.

   ```
       include("conexion.php");
       if (!isset($_POST["bot_actualizar"]))
       {
           $Id=$_POST["Id"];
           $nom=$_POST["nom"];
           $can=$_POST["can"];
           $pre=$_POST["pre"];
           $cos=$_POST["cos"];  
       }
       else
       {
           $Id=$_POST["Id"];
           $nom=$_POST["nom"];
           $can=$_POST["can"];
           $pre=$_POST["pre"];
           $cos=$_POST["cos"];
           $sql="UPDATE articulo SET nombre=:miNom, cantidad=:miCan, precio=:miPre, 
           costo=:miCos WHERE Id_campo=:miId";
           $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);
           $resultado->execute(array(":miId"=>$Id, ":miNom"=>$nom, ":miCan"=>$can, 
           ":miPre"=>$pre, ":miCos"=>$cos));
       }
   ```